# Problems of links generated by Laravel 5 Paginator

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-5

I came across a weird problem when I tried to use Paginator in Laravel 5.
The data and pagination information were prepared, but when I called $model->render() in blade the links to pages were simply wrong.

Here is some sample code in controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $articles = Article::latest('published_at')->paginate(3);
    return view('articles/index')->with('articles',$articles);
}
```

And the code in blade:

```
{!! $articles->render() !!}
```

Lastly the code in routes:

```
Route::get('articles',array('as' => 'article-list','uses' => 'ArticleController@index'));
```

The problem is Laravel generates wrong urls to different pages as such : **example.com/articles/?page=2**, with additional / before ?.

There is a workaround to correct the url by calling setPath() before passing data to view, and links now work, like this:

```
$articles = Article::latest('published_at')->paginate(3);
$articles->setPath('articles');
return view('articles/index')->with('articles',$articles);
```

But are there other options to generate correct links to pages in Laravel 5 and I missed something?

Thank you.

---

Update on environment: xampp.

Answer (score 10):

Use this code in your blade,

```
{!! str_replace('/?', '?', $articles->render()) !!}
```

This code generate the correct url.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Vinod. But I would say, like the approach (calling setPath() ) mentioned in the question, in my opinion this is just a workaround. I really hope to get rid of writing additional code to get the same pagination links as in Laravel 4. But it seems that L5 purposely does that.