# Pagination in laravel 5 producing wrong link

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When creating pagination on users page the pagination links are not right they are with / before page=1 so the link redirect to root with 404 not found.

Controller method:

```
public function getRegister()
{
    $users = User::where("admin", 0)->paginate(3);

    return view('auth.register', compact('users'));
}
```

view

```
<?php echo $users->render(); ?>
```

users page url: http://localhost:8080/pal/public/agent/create

pagination links:http://localhost:8080/pal/public/agent/create/?page=1

when click on paging link browser redirect me to: http://localhost:8080/agent/create?page=3 and got 404 page NOT FOUND

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's, at least for now, how Laravel 5 works.

To get rid of that additional slash, you have to manually handle pagination links before rendering them.

You can either:
1) in your controller, call setPath() on the paginator instance, like this:

```
public function getRegister()
{
    $users = User::where('admin',0)->paginate(3);
    $users->setPath('your/custom/path');
    return view('your/view')->with('users',$users);
}
```

Next in your view, simply call render() and it should work as expected.

or 2) modify nothing in controller but change link format in your view, for example:

```
{!! str_replace('/?', '?', $users->render()) !!}
```

You may refer to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28424522/problems-of-links-generated-by-laravel-5-paginator) I raised before.

Hope this helps!

---

I am still looking for more elegant solution but have not got any yet :(

---

Updated on 2016-05-30

Thanks for all the up-votes. Please note that in Laravel 5.2, you don't have to hack the code in a way mentioned above any more! Calling render() in views is all that you need to do. That's great, isn't it?

Answer (score 5):

I like carter's answer, I prefer the first suggestion which is using setPath. Setting "setPath" to an empty string worked for me. :)

```
$users->setPath('');
```

Comment: great! this stupid answer takes three hours to solve.

Answer (score 0):

The best method here (without need to change the code) is to modify the .htacces file to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /pal/public/

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301] <-- removed "/" before $1
```

This way (without the note in this snippet) the links from pagination should be rendered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on carters advised:

```
    public function getRegister()
    {
       $users = User::where('admin',0)->paginate(3);
       $users->setPath('your/custom/path');
       return view('your/view')->with('users',$users);
    }
```

Add the 'url()' and concat it with the route. e.g '/admin/user/list'

```
    $users->setPath(url() . '<route>');
```