# Pagination redirect is not working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

Using render function in pagination i am getting  this url

```
http://localhost/laravel_admin/public/undo/?page=2
```

So it will redirect wrong page so how to fix that issue

To redirect this way

```
http://localhost/laravel_admin/public/undo?page=2
```

in laravel 5 
I think minor error is in my code by i can't found that any one got this error.

Comment: what you have tried so far ? can you show your code here?

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28424522/problems-of-links-generated-by-laravel-5-paginator/29257817#29257817

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your code like this:

```
{!! str_replace('/?', '?', $yourVar->render()) !!}
```

I think this will fix your issue!

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have wrong configuration. You should set up your web server, so it point to `/laravel_admin/public` folder.